# Sklearn import issue with cron

Tags: python, cron, scikit-learn

I have a python script that use sklearn package. It runs fine when I launch it from terminal

But when I try to run this script in a cron job, it faills !

It seems that import faills

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor from
sklearn.externals import joblib
```

How can I solve this issue ?